# Проблемы записи сайта на хост

Tags: php, localhost, hosting

Здравствуйте. Проблема в том, что на локалке сайт работает отлично, а на хосте почему-то выдаёт следующее
[image: Выводит частично код файла]
Связано ли это с неправильным указанием ссылок, не знаю. Ведь страница видит напрямую связанные с ней файлы. Не кидайтесь помидорами, пожалуйста)

```
<?session_start();
require_once 'php/connect.php';
$id= $_SESSION["id"];
echo $id;
$user=R::findAll('usertable','`users_id`=? ',[$id]);
if (count($user)==0){
  echo ("<span class='lead text-center vertical_al mark'>YOU HAVEN`T TODO LISTS!</span><br/>");
}
else
{
  foreach ($user as $users) {
    echo "<table >
    <thead>
    <tr'>
    <th'><i ><i/></th>
    <th ><input type='text'>".$users->title."</p>.....
```

Comment: Могу посоветовать не использовать `<?`, а использовать `<?php`. На хосте могут быть не включены сокращённые теги

Comment: Помогло. Боже, как хорошо, когда есть такие люди)) спасибо большое!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В php.ini найди строчку short_open_tag и поставь ей значение On. Должно быть:

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Где находится файл php.ini в твоей виртуалке спрашивай у гугла.